# Java: How to add metainformation to multiple image types in a generic way

Tags: java, image-processing, metadata, javax.imageio, jai

### What needs to be done

I need to add **custom meta information** to **image files**. 
The supported types need to be: JPEG, GIF, BMP, TIF, PNG

### How is it done

I have decided to use the imageio [Standard metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/standard_metadata.html) in order to provide generic solution for all file types. 
I am also using Java Advanced Imaging library, as not all file types are supported by the general api.

Here is a code snippet of the core function that adds the metadata:

```
    public static byte[] writeCustomMetaInformation(byte[] imageByteArray, String contentType) throws IOException {
    ImageWriter writer = null;

    String formatName = "javax_imageio_1.0";

    ImageOutputStream stream = null;
    if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("gif")) {
        IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
        registry.registerServiceProvider(new GIFImageWriterSpi());
        writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif").next();

    } else if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("png")) {
        writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png").next();

    } else if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("bmp")) {
        IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
        registry.registerServiceProvider(new BMPImageWriterSpi());
        writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("bmp").next();

    } else if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("tif")) {
        IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
        registry.registerServiceProvider(new TIFFImageWriterSpi());
        writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tif").next();

    } else { //by default jpeg
        writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
    }

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray));

    ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    /*
     * Add metadata to the file
     * See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/standard_metadata.html
     * for reference on default image metadata DTD
     */
    IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);

    IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode(formatName);

    //Add RGB tag, otherwise BMP writing throws NPE
    IIOMetadataNode chroma = new IIOMetadataNode("Chroma");
    IIOMetadataNode colorSpaceType = new IIOMetadataNode("ColorSpaceType");
    colorSpaceType.setAttribute("name", "RGB");
    chroma.appendChild(colorSpaceType);
    root.appendChild(chroma);

    IIOMetadataNode text = new IIOMetadataNode("Text");
    IIOMetadataNode textEntry = new IIOMetadataNode("TextEntry");
    textEntry.setAttribute("keyword", "metainformation");
    textEntry.setAttribute("value", "This is some custom meta information!");
    textEntry.setAttribute("encoding", "UTF-8");
    textEntry.setAttribute("language", "EN");
    textEntry.setAttribute("compression", "none");
    text.appendChild(textEntry);

    root.appendChild(text);

    metadata.mergeTree(formatName, root);

    // writing the data
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);

    writer.setOutput(stream);

    IIOImage img = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, metadata);
    writer.write(metadata, img, writeParam);
    stream.close();

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

### What is the result

I use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)'s *identify -verbose* to view the result of adding the meta information.

1. JPG, PNG and GIF files have meta information added
2. BMP and TIF either does not have the meta information added, or ImageMagick cannot read it.

So, does anyone know why meta information added to BMPs and TIFs doesn't seem to take effect? Is Standard Metadata DTD not applicable to them? Should I use BMP/TIF metadata instead?

If you want to test the behavior, here is a link to [completely set-up project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1uifmpwgc3rmxlh/NrIuYttCgz/Metadata.zip)  that demonstrates the conversion and its problems.

Comment: Trying to reproduce your issues with sun jdk 1.6 but without JAI, I see the custom meta info included in the GIF as a comment, and `identify` says so. I fail to modify the BMP metadata as it is read-only. One possible reason for the empty files might be that you do `baos.toByteArray()` before `stream.close()` so perhaps the data wasn't flushed to your `baos` yet?

Comment: Well spotted! That was the problem with not generated files. I will edit my question with the new source code and the JAI problems.